# Any way to Save form data without Submit form using $("#Form").serializeArray()?

Tags: jquery, save, buttonclick, form-data, serializearray

Any way to **Save form data without Submitting form** using $("#Form").**serializeArray**(). When I'm using serializeArray, it works only with form submit and **not working with a button click** 
When i call this function in from cshtml page, I not getting form data in my controller (Model).
My Code is,

```
function SaveCall() {
 $("#ItemData").val(JSON.stringify($("#jqxOpStockGrid").jqxGrid('getboundrows')));

$.ajax({
    url: '/INVOpeningStock/create',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#INVOpeningStock_Form").serializeArray(),
    cache: false,
    aync: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.success) {

        } else {



        }
    }
});
}
```

**Ajax call hitting in my controller method. But the parameter model was empty.
My Controller Method is:**

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(INVOpeningStock invopeningstock )
    {
     //Method Body
    }
```

**My cshtml Page Code is**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "INVOpeningStock_Form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset class="fieldset">
<table width="100%" align="center" class="textleft">
  <tr>
     <td width="20%">
         <div class="editor-label">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cName)
         </div>
     </td>
     <td width="80%" align="left">
          <div class="editor-field">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cName, new { maxlength = 50,  @class = "textbox mediumtxt reqtext" })
          </div>
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cName, "", new { @class =  "required" })
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that you use with a button click where it doesn't work?

Comment: Please check the question that I was modified now

Comment: @dan goodspeed , Please check and respond

Comment: @Html?  I don't know what language that is.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed its razor markup, dnt think abt it. Is it possible to get data by form.serializeArray() without submitting a form. If yes please suggest the code.

Comment: Have you tried using .serialize() instead of .serializeArray()?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I'm getting data When I used

$("form").serializeArray()
Instead of

$("#INVOpeningStock_Form").serializeArray()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting data When I used

```
$("form").serializeArray()
```

Instead of

```
$("#INVOpeningStock_Form").serializeArray()
```